# Cómo implemento MATERIAL ICONS versión ROUNDED?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, programación-móvil, icons

soy nueva en REACT NATIVE y necesito usar **material icons rounded** en el proyecto . Estoy buscando en la documentación, pero no tengo ni idea de cómo aplicarla, solo puedo con la versión regular completa. ¿Alguien puede ayudarme? Graciaaaas!

```
import MaterialIcons from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialIcons';

  return <MaterialIcons name={iconName} size={size} color={color} />;
```

Esto es lo que tengo

[image: como me aparece]

y así debería estar

[image: Así me lo piden en el figma]

Nota: probé cambiando el borderRadius y no funciona

Comment: [Esta librería](https://mui.com/material-ui/icons/#usage) si tiene lo que buscas. No sé si te sirva. Sino [acá](https://fonts.google.com/icons) podes descargar todos los que te interesen.